# After installing node module @angular/cli@latest, the ng file doesn't exist

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, node-modules, npm-install

I am doing this from Git Bash on Windows 10.
The command was:

> npm install --save @angular/cli@latest

The output was:

```
+ @angular/cli@13.2.2
added 35 packages from 15 contributors and audited 914 packages in 4.852s
```

Directory node_modules@angular\cli\bin contains the following files:

```
bootstrap.js
ng.js
package.json
```

It also contains directory postinstall with these two files:

```
analytics-prompt.js
script.js
```

Everywhere I search I see references to node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng, but that file doesn't exist.  I have "ng.js" but not "ng".

Has something changed with newer versions of the Angular CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  [the file is now called ng.js](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular/cli/bin/ng.js). It was renamed since @angular/cli v.13.0.0  [by this specific commit](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/3df6fba4c1c470a332c5410b30ebe37c91d977b7#diff-48a99b1603a42413faa39371fb5ecded8227094c0d340bf34943f6ab83b4a91f).

You should not focus on that extension change, rather follow your tutorials & documents looking at the file content their pointing you at.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  I found that the change from ng to ng.js occurred on version 13.0.0 though, not 14.0.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. Updating my comment since you're sure of the version.